# C++ unable to properly use I/O

Tags: c++

To begin with, I'm fairly new to **C++**. So I need to decide whether a given point is *inside* or *outside* a circle **K**.

[image]

For that reason I have written an implementation of **Pythagoras'es theorem** and simplified the process as much as possible:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    if (x*x+y*y<4){

        cout << "Point is inside the circle" << endl;

    } else {

        cout << "Point is outside the circle" << endl;

    }

}
```

So what I want to do is make those variables a user supplied input. However, the following attempt:

```
cout << "Value for x: " << x;
cin >> x;
cout << "Value for y: " << y;
cin >> y;
```

outputs the following (as per the first line): ***Value for x: 4273158*** followed by my input.

Comment: change the order, you need first input the value of x, then output it.

Comment: I end up with an empty console that way.

Comment: @LevisFoster: So?  Did you try entering a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines

```
cout << "Value for x: " << x;
cin >> x;
cout << "Value for y: " << y;
cin >> y;
```

Should be like this

```
cout << "Please enter a value for x: ";
cin >> x;
cout << "Value for x: " << x;
cout << "Please enter a value for y: ";
cin >> y;
cout << "Value for y: " << y;
```

Because you got a value for `x` before assigning it a value because the compiler gives it a value for you, though it is not guaranteed depending on the compiler.

Comment: You should add a `cout << "Enter x\n"` and `"Enter y\n"` so he sees that on the console.

Comment: But now it doesn't show the string for the output - "Value for x/y: ".

Comment: @LevisFoster I updated my answer, now it asks to input a value for `x` and then output it, and does the same for `y`

Answer (score 0):

First assign to variable, then print it, otherwise you will be printing garbages. Do it this way

```
cout << "Enter x:";
cin >> x;
cout << "Value for x: " << x;

cout << "Enter y:";
cin >> y;
cout << "Value for y: " << y;
```